# Rewrite $f(t)$ as a combination of step functions?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$f(t) = \begin{cases}e^t, & 0 \le t  <  2\\0, & elsewhere\end{cases} $$

I wrote $$f(t) = e^tu(t) - e^tu(t-2)$$

Now I am fairly certain this is correct, however the problem states that the function should be written in terms of the same shifted variable so we can find the laplace transform of it.

In my classes they have taught us to do a kind of "trick" that involves writing a general function of the function of interest (in terms of the same shifted variable), and then equating coefficients to get a valid representation. We have only been shown how to do this with linear and polynomial functions, so I don't know how to generalize with exponentials (or circular functions - which is the next problem in my problem book).

How can I rewrite it to be in terms of the same shifted variable?

Comment: Hint: $e^t=e^2e^{t-2}$.

Comment: ooh, I didn't think of that trick! So I can just write $f(t) = e^tu(t) - e^2e^{t-2}u(t-2)$ and this is easy to take the laplace transform of. Thanks!